# Dot slash versus WORKGROUP - which is the correct domain

Tags: windows

I am trying (in code) to add a user on a non-domain machine to a computer group I created.

Assume my machine name is MACH01.
When I add the Administrator to it by giving `.\Administrator` or `MACH01\Administrator` (as far as I know, both are same), it succeeds. But since my computer is not in a domain but in the `WORKGROUP` workgroup, I also tried adding it as `WORKGROUP\Adminsitrator`, but it failed saying that such a member does not exist.

Also, in the computer properties I see the `WORKGROUP` workgroup being listed.

So why does the first succeed and second fail, when there is no listing of `MACH01` being a domain or workgroup while `WORKGROUP` is indeed a workgroup. What is the correct domain/workgroup of my computer ?

And does the `.\` notation refer to computername\username or domainname\username ?

Comment: It's worth remembering that workgroups are not something you join but rather simply a naming convenience for unstructured windows networking. This is why you can't use workgroup names to describe users and groups in the same way that you can domain names.

Answer (score 2):

A workgroup is not a domain, so there is no such account as WORKGROUP\Administrator.

A domain has accounts and groups network resources in the network explorer, a computer joins it and becomes part of that domain for administration and security.  Permission to join the domain is controlled.

A workgroup is merely a grouping in the network explorer.  The machines act independantly for security with no shared accounts and no control over which machines can join the workgroup.

Unless it is a domain controller, your computer has its own local accounts too. .\ is shorthand for this.

Answer (score 1):

".\" denotes the local machine. Therefore from what I understand you are after you can simply use this to create the local user.